# Llave foránea en migración de Laravel con tamaño del campo integer

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

Buen día, mi problema es que tengo una tabla en mi base de datos cuya llave primaria es de tamaño 11, lo normal en Laravel al crear una llave primaria con migrations es que sea de tamaño 10.
Al crear la llave foránea en a migración normalmente seria de esta forma.

```
$table->unsignedInteger('tabla_referencia_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('tabla_referencia_id')->on('tabla_referencia')->references('id')
    ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Pero esto funcionaría si la tabla **"tabla_referencia"** tuviera una llave primaria de tamaño 10, pero en mi caso, la tabla **"tabla_referencia"** tiene una lave primaria de tamaño 11 lo que da error **(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")**.

Por otro lado si hago la migración de esta manera:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('tabla_referencia_id', 11)->nullable();
$table->foreign('tabla_referencia_id')->on('tabla_referencia')->references('id')
    ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Me da un error que el campo **tabla_referencia_id** no puede ser llave primaria.

Entonces, no sé como podría crear la llave foránea con su respectiva restricción. Gracias por darse el tiempo de leer este problema, espero haber sido claro en la explicación.

Comment: ¿La llave primaria que referencias no es `UNSIGNED`? ¿Cómo creaste esa llave primaria? También sería útil saber si te refieres a mysql, postgres u otra

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, es una base de datos que ya existe en la empresa, por eso no puedo hacer cambios ya que esta en uso actualmente, y cambiarlo me crearía más problemas.
La llave primaria que referencia no es ```UNSIGNED```, esa llave primaria ya existía en esa tabla y fue creada manualmente por eso es de tamaño 11 y no 10 como generalmente los crea las migraciones de laravel, estoy trabajando en mysql.

Comment: Ok, realmente no lo he probado, pero puedes intentar creando la columna como `integer` para que coincida con la que referencia, y especificando que sea indexada para ver si te permite generar la relación, algo así `$table->integer('tabla_referencia_id')->index()->nullable();`,